# How to post multiple array Nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to post multiple array **at the same time** so i can achieve this :

```
{
 name:"John Snow",
 detail: [
    {size: "M", total: 5, color: "red"},
    {size: "S", total: 2, color: "black"}
 ]
}
```

i'm using dynamic form that can generate new input field for **detail** array. so this is my schema model :

```
const OrderSchema = new Schema({
    name:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    detail:[{
        size:{},
        color:{},
        total:{}
    }],
    date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

this is my route post :

```
router.post('/add', (req, res) => {
    let errors = [];

    if (!req.body.name) {
        errors.push({ text: 'Your customer name is empty' });
    }
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('orders/add', {
            errors: errors,
            customer: req.body.name,
            detail:[{
                size: req.body.size,
                color: req.body.color,
                total: req.body.total
            }]
        });
    } else {
        const newUser = {
            customer: req.body.name,
            detail:[{
                size: req.body.size,
                color: req.body.color,
                total: req.body.total
        }
        new Order(newUser)
            .save()
            .then(order => {
                res.redirect('/');
            })
    }
});
```

submit post is work, it just the result is not what i want :

```
{
 name:"John Snow",
 detail: [
    {size: ["M","S"], total: [5,2], color: ["red", "black"]}
 ]
}
```

i hope you can help me, thanks!

Comment: Is it a requirement to POST multiple arrays at the same time, or could you pass one array that has all the detail objects in it?

Comment: yes it is, since this form is for customer invoice . a customer could pick all the size option (S M L XL XXL XXXL) at one transaction/input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume you have your details in a `request body`.

The `req.body.details` would look like this:

```
 details: [
    {size: "M", total: 5, color: "red"},
    {size: "S", total: 2, color: "black"}
 ]
```

You could then simply save it altogether like so:

```
detail: req.body.details
```

---

Note that your Schema for details is a bit odd:

```
detail:[{
    size:{}, // seems to be a string not an object
    color:{}, // seems to be a string not an object
    total:{} // seems to be a number not an object
}]
```

Instead, I think you could do:

```
detail:[{
   size:{type: String},
   color:{type: String}, 
   total:{type: Number} 
}]
```

---

**Edit:**

Since you do not seem to validate the details, you could simply make it an array in your Schema (that is up to you and what works best).

```
detail: { type: Array }
```

In general `req.body.details` could come from wherever you make the request. It could be sorted and equal to the array that you want to save in the database.

---

I am not fully aware of what is in your `req.body.size` for example but if it is an array such as `["M","S"]` then you would extract each element and create separate objects that you would then push to the array which you would be saving in your database.

Have a look below:

```js
let size = ["M","S"]
let total = [5,2]
let color = ["red", "black"]
    
let detailsToDb = []
for (let i=0; i<size.length; i++) {
   detailsToDb.push({
     size: size[i],
     color: color[i],
     total: total[i]
   })
}
console.log(detailsToDb)
```

In your case you could use `req.body.size[i]` etc. right away, no need to initialize the variables.

```
let detailsToDb = []
  for (let i=0; i<req.body.size.length; i++) {
    detailsToDb.push({
      size: req.body.size[i],
      color: req.body.color[i],
      total: req.body.total[i]
  })
}
```

Comment: thanks, can you tell me how to get req.body.details ? since there is no input has that name attribute. and for the Schema , if i put String type it will send me error "cast to string failed for value" since i submit multiple array at the same time.

Comment: Sure, I edited the answer. Have a look. With this you could still keep the validation for types in place I believe.